# Matlab function argument issue

Tags: matlab, function, iteration

hey I have a function defined as,

```
drift = @(x1,x2,u)[x2,(a*sin(x1) - b*x2 + u)]*.05;
```

then I attempt to call it while in a triple for loop (iterating over

- x1= 1:length(n1),
- x2 = 1:length(n2)
- x3 = 1:length(nu)

)

```
next = [n1(x1), n2(x2)] + drift([n1(x1), n2(x2), nu(k)]);
```

and I get Error using myMDP>@(x1,x2,u)[x2,(a*sin(x1)-b*x2+u)]*.05 (line 148)
Not enough input arguments.

that error. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f([1,2,3]) %function call with a single parameter, which is a 3 element vector
f(1,2,3) %function call with three parameters
f([1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]) %function call with three parameters, each a 3 element vector.
```